# Rails - How do I show products with a certain code in rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a mysql table with product codes, and some products have different colours i.e. red, blue ect. which have different codes so a red pen would be REDPEN and the blue one would be BLUEPEN but in another column in my table they will have the same code to group them by i.e Colouredpen

When clicked on the pen to view the details i want to show all the different colours for that pen. How do i do this using rails?

My current code:

product_controller

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def prod
    @products = Product.uniq.pluck(:index_code)
  end

end
```

view

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr class="mouse">
        <td><%= product.product %></td>
        <td>
            <% if product.stock < 1 %>
                <p class="outstock">Out of Stock</p>
            <% else %>
                <p class="instock">In Stock</p>
            <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= product.size + ' - ' + product.colour %></td>
        <td>&pound<%= product.price %></td>
        <td><%= text_field_tag :Quantity, 1, :size => 2, :class => "qtybox" %></td>
        <td><%= image_tag("buy.png", :alt => "buy") %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <table class="divider" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 1px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: where is your code that you tried already?

Comment: I have edited the code so you can see

Answer (score 0):

To get the distinct codes, you can write :

```
Pen.select(:code).map(&:code).uniq
```

or

```
Pen.uniq.pluck(:code)
```